# How turn off the default lights on scene of Graph3D library?

Tags: light, pascalabc.net

I have such a small piece of code in PascalABC.Net IDE:

```
uses Graph3D;
begin
  View3D.ShowGridLines := False;
  View3D.BackgroundColor := Colors.Black;
  Cylinder(0,0,0,5,2,True, Colors.Blue);
  Rectangle3D(0,0,-0.01,30,30,OrtZ,OrtX,Colors.Green);
  Sphere(4, 4, 2, 2, Colors.Wheat);
end.
```

This code produce the scene:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

As you can see there is a light source. Furthermore, if we rotate the scene then we will find more than one light source. In general, one of the manuals for the Graph3D library says this:
*"By default, the scene is iluminated by ambient light source with a few directional ones."*

But how turn off these default lights? Or I have to work with them all the time?